# queria uma função que mandasse para o meu email

Tags: http

```
function envia_email(){

    var nome = $('#ContactName').val();
    var email = $('#ContactEmail').val();
    var mensagem = $('#ContactComment').val();

    //VALIDAR EMAIL 

    //VALIDAR NOME 
    if(nome == ''){
         alert('Insira um nome!');
         return false;
    }

    //VALIDAR MENSAGEM 
    if(mensagem == ''){
         alert('Insira uma mensagem!');
         return false;
    }

      $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               data: {},
               url: "http://sinditac.siteseguro.ws/email?nome="+nome+"&email="+email+"&mensagem="+mensagem,
               dataType : 'text',
               async: false,    
               success: function(msg){

                   alert(msg);
               },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert("erro");
                    FailureCallBack(data);
                }
            });   


} 


function valida_email(email){

}
```

Comment: certo, qual o problema ?

Comment: queria uma função que mandasse para o meu email direto , o jeito que coloquei funciona certo no intel XDK mais preciso de algo que eu consiga encaminhar direto pro email meu

Comment: descreve isso na pergunta antes que fechem ela